# Open excel workbooks starting with specific string listed down in cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to open workbooks from particular folder, starting with Specific string listed down in Excel sheet.

Example :
I have an excel list -

- 123456
- 567890
- 654321

And the file names are starting with these numbers are like :

- 123456_example_stringxxxx.xlsx
- 567890 example stringxx.xlsx
- 654321-example stringxxxx.xlsx

stored at : C:\Users\Desktop\Testr\Excel_Files

Below is my code, but it opens just first file, I am trying to add loop but giving errors.

Sub Macro1()

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim myPath As String

Dim myFile As String

Dim listFileName As String

Dim listName As String

Dim rowCount As Integer

rowCount = 1

listFileName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).Value

listName = listFileName & "*"

myPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Excel_Files"    

myFile = Dir(myPath & listName & ".xlsx", vbNormal)
If Len(myFile) = 0 Then
'(Here I Want to add such kind of part's list to a text file)

Else
Workbooks.Open myPath & myFile
MsgBox "Successfull", vbInformation, "Opened Sucessfully"
End If
```

End Sub

Please sugest how can I create a loop or any better & simple code for it.
In addition ,

1. I want to search names from A1 to A10
2. Msg elert "Sucessfull" shouldnt be looped, it should be displayed at the end of process.
3. When any file is not found , the process shouldnt be stopped, it will list down the objects which are not found into a text file.

Regards,
Vivek Chotaliya

Comment: How about you pull the names of all the files then do the comparison.  This could be as simply as writing the file names to a range in Excel, or adding them to an array in VBA.  Are you trying to find the first file or open all similarly-named files?  Your loop currently only opens 1 file, where you have the "myFile" being overwritten, so only the last found file will open.

Comment: @Cyril we need one click solution , due to large numbers of files with lots of variety. The common thing is that the excel filename statrts with this kind of 6 digit number. We have a list of such numbers & files stored in different folder. This code is for first file, but want to add loop, but I am having errors.

Comment: Vivek, that can all happen with a single click.  Specific to your desire to loop, you can use a for or for each loop over your range, e.g., `for each cell in rng`, where `set rng = range("a1:a10")`.  you can then use `instr(filename,cell.value)` for comparisons to the name of each file.  Close said loop using `Next`.

Comment: hi, @Cyril I am from mechanical Domain, so know lil bit about coding. I will be very thankful of you, if you can put this code to my original code above or can give any other example/sample code. Thanks in Advance -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to determine the last row used in column A, we do this using this line of code `rowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, once that's done you can use a `For Next` loop to open all files that match column A listName.

inside the `For Next` I validate if the file was found, if it wasn't then it will call a small function to create a .txt file.

Give it a try to this...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Open_Workbooks()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim listFileName As String
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim bool As Boolean

bool = False
rowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To rowCount

listFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

myPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Test\Excel_Files\"
myExtension = "*.xlsx"

myFile = Dir(myPath & listFileName & myExtension)

If Not Len(myFile) = 0 Then

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'do somenthing
'
'
'
'
'
'
'
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Else
Call Create_txt_Log(listFileName)
bool = True
End If

Next

If bool = False Then
MsgBox "Successfull", vbInformation, "Opened Sucessfully"
Else
MsgBox "Successfull but not all files where opened check text log file", vbInformation, "Opened Sucessfully"
End If

End Sub
```

**Function...**

```
Public Function Create_txt_Log(ByVal listFileName As String)

Dim Fileout As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myNotePadName As String
Dim myPath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

myNotePadName = "Not_Found.txt"
myPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Test\Files_Not_Found\"
FolderPath = myPath & myNotePadName

If FSO.FileExists(FolderPath) = False Then

Set Fileout = FSO.CreateTextFile(myPath & myNotePadName)
Fileout.Write listFileName
Fileout.Close

Else

Set Fileout = FSO.OpenTextFile(FolderPath, 8)
Fileout.Write vbCrLf & listFileName
Fileout.Close

End If

End Function
```